# check start and end available in data using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**df1**

```
id start end data
1  2001  2004 [[2004,1],[2003,2],[2002,6],[2001,0.9]]
2  2001  2004 [[2005,1],[2003,2],[2002,6],[2001,0.9]]
3  2001  2004 [[2004,1],[2003,2],[2002,6]]
```

**output**

```
id missed_one
2  2004
3  2001
```

That is the output.

I have to check from the start to end and the available in the data. If any data is missed it should print the output.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: I am creating dataframe with start and end using daterange. and I am comparing two data frames and getting missing ones

Comment: Do you only want a single year, or all missing years?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set` differencing

```
df[['start', 'end']].agg(set,1) - df.data.transform(lambda k: set([item for z in k for item in z]))

1        {}
2    {2004}
3    {2001}
dtype: object
```

Comment: @jezrael hm not sure, always glad to suggestions :)

Comment: First why both years and values to sets? Where is range? If failed if missing more years also.

Comment: @jezrael I had some typos because I named my columns differently , not sure that's what you meant haha. I put years and values unpacked to set because OP didn't explain what are each item, but can easily change in the transform function the way intended

Comment: Check my answer what I think.

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension and `zip`:

```
out = df.assign(missing=[
    [i for i in range(start, end+1) if i not in {d for d, _ in datum}] or np.nan
    for datum, start, end in zip(df.data, df.start, df.end)
])
```

```
  id  start   end                                            data missing
0   1   2001  2004  [[2004, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6], [2001, 0.9]]     NaN
1   2   2001  2004  [[2005, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6], [2001, 0.9]]  [2004]
2   3   2001  2004               [[2004, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6]]  [2001]
```

So if you want only rows with a year missing:

```
out.loc[out.missing.notnull()]
```

```
   id  start   end                                            data missing
1   2   2001  2004  [[2005, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6], [2001, 0.9]]  [2004]
2   3   2001  2004               [[2004, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6]]  [2001]
```

If you only want to show a single missing value, and not a list of missing values, you can use `next`:

```
df.assign(missing=[
    next((i for i in range(start, end+1) if i not in {d for d, _ in datum}), np.nan)
    for datum, start, end in zip(df.data, df.start, df.end)
])
```

```
   id  start   end                                            data  missing
0   1   2001  2004  [[2004, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6], [2001, 0.9]]      NaN
1   2   2001  2004  [[2005, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6], [2001, 0.9]]   2004.0
2   3   2001  2004               [[2004, 1], [2003, 2], [2002, 6]]   2001.0
```

Some timings:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

In [145]: %%timeit
     ...: out = df.assign(missing=[^M
     ...:     [i for i in range(start, end+1) if i not in {d for d, _ in datum}] or np.nan^M
     ...:     for datum, start, end in zip(df.data, df.start, df.end)^M
     ...: ])
     ...:
72.3 ms ± 1.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [146]: %%timeit
     ...: df[['start', 'end']].agg(set,1) - df.data.transform(lambda k: set([item for z in k for item in z]))
     ...:
503 ms ± 13.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can substract `set`s:

```
#if necessary convert to nested lists
import ast
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

df = df.set_index('id')
ranges = df[['start', 'end']].apply(lambda x: set(range(x['start'], x['end'] + 1)), axis=1)
data = df['data'].apply(lambda k: set([z[0] for z in k]))

out = (ranges - data).to_dict()
print (out)
{1: set(), 2: {2004}, 3: {2001}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame([(k, v1) for k, v in out.items() for v1 in v], columns=['id','missed_one'])
print (df1)
   id  missed_one
0   2        2004
1   3        2001
```

**Details**:

```
print (ranges)
id
1    {2001, 2002, 2003, 2004}
2    {2001, 2002, 2003, 2004}
3    {2001, 2002, 2003, 2004}

print (data)
id
1    {2001, 2002, 2003, 2004}
2    {2001, 2002, 2003, 2005}
3          {2002, 2003, 2004}
Name: data, dtype: object
```